# Fasm "while" problem

Tags: fasm

I'm trying to write a simple "while" in fasm that print A into DOS console 4 times. Here the code

```
org 100h
use16

jnp ciclo

ciclo:
        cmp [c],0
        jle fine

        mov ah,02h
        mov dl,'A'
        int 21h

        dec [c]
        jnp ciclo

fine: ret

c db 5
```

When i run it it prints only one A on the scren and then exit.
Sameone can help?
Thanks
Gianluca

Answer (score 4):

JNP is a conditional jump if the parity flag is not set. You want the unconditional jump (JMP) instead.